# how to make cancel button clickable while app is waiting for all tasks to finish

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, c#-4.0

Here is my MainWindow.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Loaded="EmployeesGridLoaded">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="6*" />
            <RowDefinition  />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid x:Name="gEmployees" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue" AlternationCount="2" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Row="0">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Select" Binding="{Binding Select}"  Width="1*" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LastName}" Width="3*" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}" Width="3*" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5" Grid.Row="1" >
            <Button Content="Process" Margin="5"  Click="Process_Click" />
            <Button Content="Cancel" Margin="5"  Click="Cancel_Click" />
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here is the code.

```
namespace WpfApplication2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private List<Employee> Employees = null;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void EmployeesGridLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Employees = new List<Employee>()
        {
            new Employee() { Select = false, LastName = "Silly", FirstName = "Dude" },
            new Employee() { Select = false, LastName = "Mean", FirstName = "Person" },
            new Employee() { Select = false, LastName = "New", FirstName = "Friend" },
            new Employee() { Select = false, LastName = "My", FirstName = "Buddy" },
        };

        gEmployees.ItemsSource = Employees;
    }

    private void Process_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
         {
            string[] tResults = Employees
                    .Where(x => x.Select == true)
                    .AsParallel()
                    .Select(x => this.DoSomethingWithThisEmployeee(x.LastName, x.FirstName).Result)
                    .ToArray();
        });



        Task.WaitAll(task);
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Done");
    }

    private void Cancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private Task<string> DoSomethingWithThisEmployeee(string lastName, string firstName)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<string> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
        Random rand = new Random();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(rand.Next(30000, 60000));
        tcs.SetResult(lastName + " - " + firstName);
        return tcs.Task;
    }

}
```

}

In the code, for each selected employee I have to do some long running operations. Once long running operations are done for all selected employees, the app will do something else. However when these long running operations are running I would like Cancel button to be available so that user can cancel operation. Problem is that Task.WaitAll block the UI and as a result Cancel button is not clickable. Is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: At first you can't `WaitAll` for a single task.Anyway, you should use continuation. Or move to .NET 4.5 and use asynchronous waiting.

Comment: @Hamlet: I cannot move to .NET 4.5. so continuation will not cause a block?

Comment: Continuation will be triggered after task completion.

Comment: Use cancellationtokensource to pass cancellationtoken to each task.  You'll need to handle the cancellation within the code for each task, but this allows you to start the tasks and return control to the UI.  The cancel button would then cancel the cancellationtokensource.  This all works from .Net 4

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things you are doing wrong:

1. With `async-await` [you need to use `Task.Run` instead of `Task.TaskFactory.StartNew`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx).
2. Calling `Task.Result`, `Task.Wait` or `Task.WaitAll` from the UI thread will deadlock your UI.

Using `async-await` it will be a lot easier if easier if you completely split your logic in UI and non-UI:

```
private async void Process_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var results = await ProcessAsync();

    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Done");
}
```

Asynchronous methods provide asynchronous execution logic that, most of the time, won't even require `Task.Run`.

If I understood your example, you are trying to parelelise what `DoSomethingWithThisEmployeee` does. You shouldn't be mixing `AsParallel` with `Task`s. Your processing is either CPU bound (and for that you should use `AaParallel`, if processing each item is not dependent on processing another) or blocking (and for that you should use `Task`s).

Assuming your processing code is blocking, you can write it like this:

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<string>> ProcessAsync()
{
    var tasks =
        from e in this.Employees
        where e.Select
        select this.DoSomethingWithThisEmployeee(e.LastName, e.FirstName);

    return await Task.WhenAll(runningTasks);
}
```

In order to support cancelation, you need to use a `CancellationToken` and pass it along to all code that accepts a `CancellationToken` and use it to cancel execution:

```
private CancellationTokenSource tcs;
private async void Process_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        this.tcs = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var results = await ProcessAsync(tcs.Token);

        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Done");
    }
    catch OperationCanceledException ex
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Canceled");
    }
    catch Exception ex
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Error");
    }
}

private async void Cancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.tcs.Cancel();
}

private async Task<IEnumerable<string>> ProcessAsync(CancellationToken ct)
{
    var tasks =
        from e in this.Employees
        where e.Select
        select this.DoSomethingWithThisEmployeee(e.LastName, e.FirstName, ct);

    return await Task.WhenAll(runningTasks);
}
```

There's also a problem with your `DoSomethingWithThisEmployeee` method. It always returns a completed task after having "processed" the data.

I believe what you wanted was something more along these lines:

```
private Task<string> DoSomethingWithThisEmployeee(string lastName, string firstName, CancellationToken ct)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<string> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

    Random rand = new Random();
    System.Threading.Timer t;
    t = new System.Threading.Timer(
        () =>
        {
            try
            {
                t.Dispose();

                tcs.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                tcs.TrySetResult(lastName + " - " + firstName);
            }
            catch OperationCanceledException ex
            {
            }
            catch Exception ex
            {
                tcs.TrySetException(ex);
            }
        },
        rand.Next(30000, 60000),
        Timeout.Infinite);

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

You might also need to use `Task.ConfigureAwait(false)`, but I'll leave that to you.

Read the articles on [my `async-await` curation](http://curah.microsoft.com/45553/asyncawait-general) to learn the basics (and not so basics) about `async-await`.

Note: Some code might not compile and require minor adjustments.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response, however, I am constrained to using .NET 4.0.

Comment: OK! I missed the `C#-4.0` tag. But you did tag the question with `async-await`, which is __C# 5.0__. Can't you use [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/ "Microsoft Async")?

Comment: that was my bad. The organization I am working with have some strange processes that one has to go through when bringing in dependency on a newer library :( I will prefer to do it without going through that painful process, if possible.

Comment: You can still use `CancellationToken`s and threads instead of tasks.